# React Native invoke mDNS endpoints

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, iot, esp8266

I am building an IOT device for my home and have mDNS responder on it (to avoid static IP setup for IoT devices).

Devices are to be controlled with React Native Android app, but the same seems to be not working and am getting Network error (using Axios).

My endpoints have changed from `http://192.168.0.2/setSettings` to `http://mymdnstest.local/setSettings` same works from windows chrome browser but not from android browser as well.

I came across [zeroconf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zeroconf) but it seems it searches for mdns URL but I am looking for more of invoking them.

Note: the mDNS endpoint is known to my React Native app.

Comment: Android doesn't support mDNS.

Comment: @romkey any alternate? I have seen android apps to which we feed mDNS address and they rightly gave back the IP associated. So seems android does support mDNS now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeroconf actually works, the issue is with emulator it doesnt let us know if it works.. If you test it with physical device will get to know the mDNS details.